# Proving any automorphism of the group $\Bbb R^\times$

Tags: automorphic-forms

Let$\Bbb R^\times$ denote the non-zero real numbers. Prove that any automorphism of the group $\Bbb R^\times$  under multiplication maps positive to positive numbers and negative numbers to negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Positive numbers $a$ can be characterized by the fact that there exists a number $b$ such that $a=b^2$. This property survives an automorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x > 0$, and choose $y$ so that $y^2 = x$. Then
$$\phi(x) = \phi(y\cdot y) = \phi^2(y) > 0.$$
If $x < 0$, then $-x > 0$, so
$$\phi(-x) = \phi(-1)\phi(x) > 0.$$
This implies $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(-1)$ have the same signs. From
$$\phi(1) = \phi^2(-1),$$
either $\phi(-1) = 1$ or $\phi(-1) = -1$. Since the former would imply $\phi$ is not injective, $\phi(-1) < 0$, and $\phi(x) < 0$.

Comment: No problem.  I'll delete my comment...as it isn't relevant after the edit.